# Match a string/sequence by skipping characters

Tags: python, regex, string

Match a string with multiple substrings: The substrings can be directly matched or the characters can be skipped for the match.

For example,

Input - `AABCCAADABDC`
Substrings - `AABA` and `BDC`

`AABA` and `BDC` are valid sequences:

- `BDC`is a direct match
- `AABA` is matched by skipping `C`

How to match a substring by skipping the characters? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at the [regular expression library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Hi @Genesis, welcome to SO. Do you want to solve this question using regex or is any solution acceptable?

Comment: @user13427216 I know about regex but I don't know how to skip characters, it is also tricky as I do not know which sequence to match while writing the regex, it is dynamically taken from a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def match(input_seq, substring, threshold=2):
    '''
    Accepts @param: input_seq and
    @param: substring to check if
    substring pattern is present
    in @input_seq
    '''
    is_direct_match = substring in input_seq
    if is_direct_match:
        return True
    
    substring_idx = 0
    input_seq_idx = 0
    input_seq_revisit_idx = 0

    is_matching = False
    num_char_miss = 0

    while(input_seq_idx < len(input_seq)):
        substring_char = substring[substring_idx]
        input_seq_char = input_seq[input_seq_idx]
        input_seq_idx = input_seq_idx + 1
        
        if substring_char == input_seq_char:
            if not is_matching: # first character matched
                is_matching = True
                input_seq_revisit_idx = input_seq_idx
            substring_idx = substring_idx + 1
        elif is_matching:
            num_char_miss = num_char_miss + 1
        
        if num_char_miss > threshold: # reset and start a new search
            num_char_miss = 0
            substring_idx = 0
            input_seq_idx = input_seq_revisit_idx
            is_matching = False
        if substring_idx == len(substring):
            break
        # print(input_seq_char, substring_char, input_seq_char == substring_char, is_matching, num_char_miss)

    is_skip_match = substring_idx == len(substring)
    return is_skip_match

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_seq = "AABCCCAADAAABCCABDC"
    substrings = ["AABA", "BDC", "AEABA"]

    for substring in substrings:
        is_valid_seq = match(input_seq=input_seq, substring=substring, threshold=2)
        result = "is a valid"
        if not is_valid_seq:
            result = "is not a valid"

        print("{} {} sequence in {}".format(substring, result, input_seq))
```

The above code uses `in` for checking direct matching. For skip matching, each character is matched with the input sequence. If all characters from substring are not matched in the input sequence, then it's not a valid sequence.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, this works! My original use case actually has list of strings, I managed to adapt your code to work for the list. However, is there any way to set a threshold for skipping characters? If more than 2 invalid characters come in between a valid sequence, I'd like the program to stop matching and move on to the next sequence

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I will modify the function such that the `AABA` is a valid sequence in `AABCCCAADAAABCCABDC` and `AABA` is not a valid sequence in `AABCCCAADAABDC` for threshold 2.

Comment: Hopefully, that solves the problem.

Comment: @Genesis, if the answer solves your question, please accept.